# How to get a right-click item which is not selected in Java Swing's list?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlist

I have a Java Swing Jlist, and I know how to process a left-click and right-lick on a "selected item", but my question here is : If item 1 is currently selected, but when I right click on item 3, how to get that item's info/identity ? For example, in the following image, as you can see,

[image]

Salsa_2015_03_01_1 is selected, but if now I right mouse click on Salsa_2015_03_01_3, how to get that item's info in the following sample code :

```
    list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
      {
        String File_Path=File_Map.get(list.getSelectedValue().toString()).getAbsolutePath();

        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
        {
//          Out("Left-Click");
        }
        else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
        {
        }
       }
     });
```

Right now the MouseEvent e contains only the selected item, is there a way to detect which one is the mouse clicked item ? What I want to achieve is save a step : left-click on item 3 then right click on it to do extra process. But I want to skip the left-click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want [`JList#locationToIndex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#locationToIndex(java.awt.Point))

*Modified example from JavaDocs*

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
     if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
         int index = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
         System.out.println("Item " + index);
      }
 }
```